# Could import css with css layer in React?

Tags: css, reactjs

I try to import css with css layer in React.

I test to import with layer in css file and after import with React :

```
@import 'theme.css' layer(theme);
@import 'utilities.css' layer(utilities);

@layer theme, utilities;
```

I try to define layer in each file and after import in react :

```
@layer theme{
my css
}
```

Isn't work. React see only the last layer. Other layers are ignored.

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71481824/background-color-overridden-even-after-reversing-the-order-of-css-layers/71482235#71482235)

Comment: Identical to question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/74791017/104380